# Compare the intercept and y-intercept of the new model with the old model

Tags: linear-model, model-evaluation

If we have two simple linear models (old and new), is there a good way to evaluate whether the newly developed model is sufficiently different from the previous model?

For example, let's assume there are two expressions like this.
[Eq. old] Y = 1.53(± 0.01)X + 10(±0.23)
[Eq. new] Y = 1.50(± 0.01)X + 9(±0.23)

In this case, the values of *a* and *b* of the linear model (*y = ax + b*) do not overlap statistically, so they look different.
Additionally, there appears to be a slight difference in the R2, RMSPE, and CCC values evaluated using observed data.

However, the *a* and *b* values of the new model do not seem significantly different (numerically) compared to the previous model.

In this situation, is there a way to find out whether the *a* and *b* values of the two models are actually meaningful changes?

Thank you.

[Add]
Both models were derived from independent data sets.

Comment: This could be solved nicely (maybe) if you have access to the data, merge the two and build one model, then you can compare the intercepts and slopes.

Comment: Are the data which went into fitting the two models different and independent? (This is essential information, so please add it to your question rather than responding to the comment.)

Comment: `is there a way to find out whether the a and b values of the two models are actually meaningful changes?` That is not a statistical question. That is a matter of what the experts in the domain believe. Do they (maybe you're one of them) believe these differences to be important?

Comment: What sense does it make to compare $a$ (the intercept) to $b$ (the slope) *within a given model* when your question appears to concern comparing two different models?? And what exactly do you mean by "not overlap statistically"?

Comment: @Dave Yes. Actually I don't think there is much difference between the two values in practical terms. Nonetheless, I wanted to get an idea if there are any other ways to evaluate this. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You need to specify your objective. E.g., if "in practical terms" means "the predictions agree within observational error," then the answer depends on the range of values of $x$ you are interested in--and you need to tell us what that range is. But if it means you want to test whether the two models are giving you inconsistent information about $(a,b),$ then that's a different question with a very different answer! E.g., if the range is around $x\approx 100,$ you might conclude the models give substantially different predictions; but near $x\approx -33,$ they're indistinguishable.

Comment: @whuber I wanted to evaluate whether the new model (eq. new) had any meaningful differences compared to the existing model (eq. old). Perhaps there is no statistical (objective) judgment standard for this, and it should be based on experience. Thanks.

Comment: Again: differences *in what property* specifically?  Moreover, as remarked by @Dave earlier, "meaningful" is something to be determined by consumers of your analysis ("experts in the domain"), not by any statistical procedure.